# Google sheets - how can I use functions to resort my table in a way charts can read it well

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using app sheets to see what I do in a day. I select the task I am starting on the app and app sheets dump the data into a table in google sheets.

I have made an example of what this looks like. Sheet1 is what it looks like at the moment and sheet2 is what I would like it to look like (or something else that will help charts read it).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GF6cjlNMSTJov4G6ZMusXSWS-DMwnK4SgQqNs8d8uws/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi and welcome. AAMOI, do you have the ability to record the time ended for each activity?

Answer (score 0):

The same question was answered at [How can i collect and add values related to a value next to it in a table and add them to another](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/118255847) and the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GF6cjlNMSTJov4G6ZMusXSWS-DMwnK4SgQqNs8d8uws/edit#gid=1371819045) contains the accepted solution. Pasting here for prosperity:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Duration"; 
    array_constrain( 
      iferror( 1 / ( sign(B3:B) / (C3:C + B3:B - (C2:C + B2:B)) ) ), 
      rows(B2:B), 
      1 
    ) 
  } 
)

=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Dur. dateserial"; 
    to_pure_number(D2:D) 
  } 
)
 
=query( 
  'Calculate durations'!A1:E, 
  "select C, sum(E) 
   where A is not null 
   group by C 
   pivot A", 
  1 
)
```